# Why does the npm userconfig not get picked up?

Tags: node.js, configuration, npm

By default, NPM stores the user config in `~/.npmrc`. I had a load of stuff in my user config which I didn't want to interfere with for my main project, but I was switching to a second project which required different configuration, so I just did:

`npm config set userconfig C:\path\to\another\directory\.npmrc`.

To my surprise, NPM added a new entry `userconfig` into my existing **user** config at `~/.npmrc`. This doesn't make sense to me - seems NPM needs to know where the user config is in order to find out where it is!

Now NPM ignores any properties I put into my new NPMRC file and only takes properties from `~/.npmrc`. Even more strangely, `npm config list` contains a userconfig header (semicolon-prefixed line) specifying my new location, but the contents come from `~/.npmrc`.

For example, if I set my email as "foo@example.com" in the `~/.npmrc` and as "bar@example.com" in my new NPMRC, `npm config list` reports something like this:

```
; cli configs
user-agent = "npm/3.10.8 node/v6.9.1 win32 x64"

; userconfig C:\path\to\another\directory\.npmrc
(... other properties ...)
email = "foo@example.com"
(... other properties ...)
userconfig = "C:\path\to\another\directory\.npmrc"

; builtin config undefined

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = C:\
; HOME = C:\Users\MyUsername
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

The value has come from `~/.npmrc` despite appearances (I double-checked the value in the new NPMRC is definitely "bar@example.com").

I thought this might be a bug in NPM so I upgraded my Node/NPM to the latest version, but it still behaves the same way. Am I using `userconfig` wrong and how should it work?

Comment: This stuff has already bitten mi in the back. According to docs (https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc#per-user-config-file) it suppose point to your other .npmrc described by userconfig option, but it doesn't do that. However the most annoying thing was the fact that it seemed to work at first. I setup userconfig using npm config set, and npm config list started to list the option from the other file. However once I closed the terminal it stopped workind, and I couldn't reproduce it since :(

Answer (score 12):

From https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config

> **npmrc Files**
>
> The four relevant files are:
>
> - per-project configuration file (**/path/to/my/project/.npmrc**)
> - per-user configuration file (defaults to **$HOME/.npmrc;** configurable via CLI
>     option --userconfig or environment variable **$NPM_CONFIG_USERCONFIG**)
> - global configuration file (defaults to **$PREFIX/etc/npmrc**; configurable
>     via CLI option **--globalconfig** or environment variable
>     **$NPM_CONFIG_GLOBALCONFIG**)
> - npm's built-in configuration file (**/path/to/npm/npmrc**)

### Fix

Call a command like `npm --userconfig /another/path/to/npmrc install` and it will use that instead of the ~/.npmrc file

Comment: I prefer setting $NPM_CONFIG_USERCONFIG variable since that will reflect every command in that session (or persistently). Using --userconfig will only work for that one command (though that could be desired)